# Change color of \pgfshadepath{ball}{0}

Tags: tikz-pgf

There is already a predefined shading for spherical objects, which is invoked via the "ball" option, but I haven't found a way to switch its color from the default blue to red when using it outside of the "tikzpicture" environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{balls}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength/floor(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/5pt)]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfusepath{}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}{2.5pt}
    \pgfshadepath{ball}{0}{color=red}
    \pgfusepath{}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decorate, decoration={balls}, color=red](0, 0) -- (2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Penguin, welcome to the site. Are you perhaps looking for `ball color=red`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Well, I've tried to use the "ball color=red" flag, it didn't result in changing the color to red no matter where I've put it. Could you maybe give me a hint where to put this question in order to see an effect?

Comment: @PenguinNurse: Ah, I might be misunderstanding the quesiton. I used `\draw[decorate, decoration={balls}, ball color=red](0, 0) -- (2, 0);`, which worked, but you want to define the color within your `\pgfdeclaredecoration`, correct?

Comment: That's actually perfect. Your solution works fine for me, although it might create redundancy for people using the decoration many times.